# CodeIgniter : Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php

When I try to run http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/  I get this error

> A PHP Error was encountered  Severity: Warning   Message:
>   mysqli::real_connect():  (HY000/1049): Base 'niks' inconnue
>   Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php Line Number: 135   Backtrace: 
>   File: C:\wamp\www\CodeIgniter-3.0.0\index.php  Line: 292  Function:
>   require_once   A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>   Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php   Line Number: 500

Comment: check your DB name , username and password

Comment: in autoload.php file, include 'database' in libraries array

Answer (score 0):

check

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['default']['username'] = "root";
$db['default']['password'] = "root";
$db['default']['database'] = "dbname";
```